# change data frame in R

Tags: r

i have a data frame generated inside a for loop and have this structure

```
    V1 V2 V3
1   a  a  1
2   a  b  3
3   a  c  2
4   a  d  1
5   a  e  3
6   b  a  3
7   b  b  1
8   b  c  8
9   b  d  1
10  b  e  1
11  c  a  2
12  c  b  8
```

the data is longer than this , but that's the idea that i want 
(transform it to a wide table [V1 by V2])

V3 is a value based on (V1, V2)

i want to rearrange data to be like this (with first col is the unique of V1 and first row is the unique of V2 and data between them are from V3 )

```
  a b c d e
a 1 3 2 1 3
b 3 1 8 1 1
c 2 8 2 8 2
d 1 1 5 7 2
e 3 5 9 5 3
```

thnx in advance.

Comment: is the example output really what you want? The text "the first col is the unique of V1..." makes me think that there should only be `a` and `b`...the output you show has `a-e`

Comment: @Chase: hello , i only gave an example of the data

Comment: it's still a mystery to me what exactly you are trying to do. Perhaps a more complete example would help. Your matrix as it stands does not seem consistent with the data-frame, e.g. `[a,a]` has 1 in the matrix but according to the data-frame it should be 2.

Comment: @Prasad Chalasani  : hello , i changed my question , is it clear now ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reproducible example of yours:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"),     V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,     1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"),     V3 = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 8L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

And compute a basic crosstable based on your variables:

```
> xtabs(V3~V1+V2, df)
   V2
V1  a b c d e
  a 1 3 2 1 3
  b 3 1 8 1 1
  c 2 8 0 0 0
```

I hope you meant this :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the data showed in the edited question. As you might see, the first rows are exact same to the ones provided in the question, so I *think* this output is desired. Please comment to let me know if this not, and why not the required output.

Comment: Hello , thanks for your help , but this is not the desired output , my output should be a new data frame with the row names is the unique of V1 and the column names is the unique of V2 and inside it is the values or V3 that correspond to (V1,V2). but your code only work on this data , i want something that can change any data frame to wide(V1 by V2) , thnx in advance

Comment: @weblover: I do not understand what you mean under that the above code works only on this data... Just use the `xtabs` command (that I suggested above) to your specific data table, and you will get the desired output. You have to change the V1, V2 and V3 to the variable names of your data sets of course, I used these as you proposed in your question. If your problem is with the class of the output, then transform it to data.table by e.g. `as.data.frame(unclass(xtabs(V3~V1+V2, df)))`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your data-frame, assuming a unique V3 is mapped to each V1,V2 combination, you can do it with

```
with(df, tapply(V3, list(V1,V2), identity))
```

Comment: I don't think this produces the example output above. I also don't think the OP is consistent between his description of what he wants and the output he shows, so I guess it's ambiguous what should be produced.

Comment: @weblover: I've just realized my answer is really similar to the one given by @Prasad Chalasani besides showing zeros instead of NAs. Could you please specify what you meant under "did not do it" and also what to do exactly :)

Comment: @weblover: I *think* I see what you want, please check the answers and please write back what is the exact problem with the output. I also updated my answer (see below) based on your new example dataset, though the algorithm used in the answer did not change.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, perhaps slightly more baroque, for widening a dataframe from a third column on the basis of the first two... with Chase that the OP has not given an unambiguous problem description:

```
 df2 <- expand.grid(A=LETTERS[1:5], B=LETTERS[1:5])
 df2$N <- 1:25
 mtx <- outer(X=LETTERS[1:5],Y=LETTERS[1:5], FUN=function(x,y){
                        df2[intersect(which(df2$A==x), which(df2$B==y)), "N"] })
 colnames(mtx)<-LETTERS[1:5]; rownames(mtx)<-LETTERS[1:5]
 mtx
  A  B  C  D  E
A 1  6 11 16 21
B 2  7 12 17 22
C 3  8 13 18 23
D 4  9 14 19 24
E 5 10 15 20 25
```

I'm sure there are many other strategies using `reshape` in base or `dcast` in reshape2.

Comment: @weblover: As others have said... it's up to you now to post an example that better describes the data and matching output. No one can help when there is no discernible connection.